# Testing a Docker image in Jenkins

Tags: python, docker, jenkins

I've been searching around but I can't seem to find anything on how to do this except using curl (but that is only for integration tests).

I have setup my Jenkins to get codes from GitHub, build the Docker image and push a repo. This I have done. What I can't find is how to test the Docker image before and after build. I have the unit and integration test in the GitHub repo, so it is cloned together with the codes.

My application is a flask app, using Flask and JWT_Flask_Extended.

How can I code the jenkinsfile to run the unit test before build and integration test after build of the Docker image.

I'm using python3. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: This is all entirely too broad. The only reasonable answer to "How do I run the tests" is "Tell Jenkins to run the tests." `python -m unittest discover` might do it, or else we'll need _much_ more information....

Comment: So, for the unit test, I just need to do a python unittest command and it should work? That's easy. I'll try that but how would Jenkins know the test have passed? Are there settings I need? How about the intergration test on the Docker image? What other details is needed for that, so that you guys can help me?

Comment: Well this is a Flask app, so I'm guessing that the integration test is a set of web calls pointed at a running container? Stand the container up and run your tests~

Comment: This app reads and writes to a database, the calls are POST (json). Sorry for being stupid but this is my first time doing this and I have nobody in the company to ask for help. Do you mean that after the image has been created, I'd run it with a docker command and how do I run the test? Do I do a unittest command again? Or is there no need to if I run the integration test before building the docker image?

Comment: How do you run the tests in your local environment? Sounds like you have a database that's standing up -- is that specified as part of a docker-compose.yml or etc?

Comment: Yes, I have a database but I've never done a unit/integration test on the docker itself. It has been a, let's run manually and see if it can do some thing and then it get uploaded to the repo.

Comment: Does the integration test ship into the docker image? If so `docker run` can tell a running container to execute a command (see the common `docker run -it bash <container_name>`)

Comment: you can reach out through email if you like. This isn't a good StackOverflow question but I should have time to help in general. My github is linked from my SO profile